# Can't reduce background photo size

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I can't seem to reduce the size of the background photo behind the profile pic.  It's the blurred pic in the screen shot.[image]

Notice how the background pic appears to have line across the middle...that's where I want it cut off.

```
<ion-content padding class="profilePhoto center-text" *ngIf="loggedInUser">
<ion-card class="prflBg">
  <ion-card-content >
        <div [ngSwitch]="this.cameraServiceProvider.photo0">
            <div *ngSwitchDefault>
                <img [src]="this.cameraServiceProvider.photo0" 
            (click)="Present('photo0.png')"/>
            </div>
            <div *ngSwitchCase="'UseButton'">
                <img src="assets/img/add-an-image.png" 
               (click)="selectPhoto('photo0.png')"/>
            </div>      
        </div>
    </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>



    .prflBg {
    ion-card-content{
    background-image: url('../assets/img/headerBg.png');
    background-size: 320px 158px;
    object-fit: contain !important;
    }
```

I only want like 60% of top card covered by the background pic but it's covering the entire card.

Comment: background-repeat:no-repeat,

Comment: That works great.  The cards and the image doesn't cover the entire width.  How would I get both of them to cover the entire width of the screen...the background image and the ionic cards?